# Trying to decipher a text file with an algorithm

Tags: java

I have deciphering method that *should* open a test file with encrypted text, then read and decipher each line of text that I read in from the input file. The text file is called mystery.txt.
I can get the method to work when only inputting single characters but I can't get it to work where I open the .txt file and decipher line by line. I have tried calling my readFile() just before the algorithm but I get a null pointer exception in the for (i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) . I have never done anything even similar to this before and really don't know how to go about doing it.

The algorithm should read each line and decipher it using the crypt1 & crypt2 variables.

Using my readFile() and writeFile() methods, I need my cipherDecipherString() method to be able to  Write a method which opens the file, reads each line that it contains one at a time, deciphers each line which is read in and writes the resulting text to the screen and to an output file.

Dechiphering method:

```
public static String cipherDecipherString(String text)

{
 // These are global. Put here for space saving
 private static final String crypt1 = "cipherabdfgjk";
 private static final String crypt2 = "lmnoqstuvwxyz";

    // declare variables
    int i, j;
    boolean found = false;
    String temp="" ; // empty String to hold converted text
    readFile();
    for (i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) // look at every chracter in text
    {
        found = false;
        if ((j = crypt1.indexOf(text.charAt(i))) > -1) // is char in crypt1?
        {           
            found = true; // yes!
            temp = temp + crypt2.charAt(j); // add the cipher character to temp
        }
        else if ((j = crypt2.indexOf(text.charAt(i))) > -1) // and so on
        {
            found = true;
            temp = temp + crypt1.charAt(j);
        }
        if (! found) // to deal with cases where char is NOT in crypt2 or 2
        {
            temp = temp + text.charAt(i); // just copy across the character
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

My readFile method:

```
public static void readFile()
{
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String InputFileName;
    String nextLine;
    clrscr();
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file that is to be READ (e.g. aFile.txt: ");
    InputFileName = Genio.getString();
    try
    {
        fileReader = new FileReader(InputFileName);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader); 
        nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while (nextLine != null)
        {
            System.out.println(nextLine);
            nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, there has been a problem opening or reading from the file");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (bufferedReader != null)
        {
            try
            {
                bufferedReader.close();    
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("An error occurred when attempting to close the file");
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

my writeFile() method:

```
public void writeFile()
{
    String myString;
    clrscr();
    System.out.println("Begin typing the contents to you wish to WRITE to file: ");
    myString = Genio.getString();
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;
    try
    {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream("writing.txt");
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream); 
        printWriter.write(myString);
        printWriter.println("\n");
        while (!myString.equals(""))
        {
            myString = Genio.getString();
            printWriter.print(myString + "\n");
        }

        System.out.println("File: 'writing.txt' has been saved with the contents above.\n\nYou can now open this file using the other options in the menu screen.");
        pressKey();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, there has been a problem opening or writing to the file");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (printWriter != null)
        {
            // close the file
            printWriter.close();    
        }
    }
}
```

Now I thought that I would just be able to call my readFile() method then go into the decipher code and it let work it's way through the file but I cannot get it to work at all.

Genio is the class that deals with user input. I didn't want to go overkill with the code but can post add it if it's needed. Thank you!

Comment: From your incomplete code, it is hard to guess what works and what doesn't. Please edit your question to at least: 1. State what steps you followed, 2. state your expected outcome, 3. state the actual outcome.

Comment: @llogiq Hi. I have tried calling my readFile() just before the algorithm but I get a null pointer exception in the for `(i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)` . I have never done anything even similar to this before and really don't know how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets call your `cipherDecipherString` as `decode`, then put in another method called `decode` that takes two file paths. One is a source file path, other is a destination. Then here's how the code will look like:

```
private static final String crypt1 = "cipherabdfgjk";
private static final String crypt2 = "lmnoqstuvwxyz";

private String decode (String line)
{
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder (line.length ());

  for (int i = 0; i < line.length (); ++i)
  {
    char ch = line.charAt (i);

    int index1 = crypt1.indexOf (ch);
    int index2 = crypt2.indexOf (ch);

    if (index1 != -1)
    {
      result.append (crypt2.charAt (index1));
    }
    else if (index2 != -1)
    {
      result.append (crypt1.charAt (index2));
    }
    else
    {
      result.append (ch);
    }
  }

  return result.toString ();
}

/* Takes file source, reads it line by line, decodes each line, then writes the
 * decoded lines to the file destination.
 */
public void decode (String fileSource, String fileDestination) throws IOException
{
  Files.write (Paths.get (fileDestination), 
               Files.lines (Paths.get (fileSource)).
               map (this::decode).
               collect (Collectors.toList ()));
}
```

This requires Java 8 though.
If you have any issues in your `cipherDecipherString` method, then let me know.

These are the required imports:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this a bit out of my realm to be honest though. I need it to work using the `cipherDecipherString` as it is, using either the code from my other methods (read and write) or calling them. I tried a number of variations to try and get it to work but with no luck :/

Comment: @DarkBlueMullet: I have updated the decode method, which is just a refined version of your `cipherDecipherString`. Now it should work, if you just call the other `decode` method and provide it with a source file path and a destination file path.

Comment: @DarkBlueMullet: Your approach isn't working, cause in your `readFile` method, you are just printing out the lines of the files, which can't be used by your `cipherDecipherString` method.

Comment: I really appreciate the help but I can't get it to work. I may need to go back and re-think. I am still new java and programming in general. I am using BlueJ and the second part of the code you wrote and some of the imports do not work. I really do appreciate the help though. If you wanted to read the description of what I have to do and had the time, I could link you to it, including the files? I appreciate that this might be a bit much though!

Comment: Make sure you have the latest BlueJ installed, cause earlier versions don't support Java 8, and also make sure you have JDK 8 installed properly. The Collectors import wouldn't work if you don't have Java 8. If you install that, and use the latest version of BlueJ, the issue won't come. If any issue still persist, let me know.

Comment: You can provide the description of what you intend to do. Nothing's too much here, if you learn something in the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65207/discussion-between-aman-agnihotri-and-darkbluemullet).